# Converting belongs_to with includes from Rails 3 to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble converting a belongs_to relationship with an **includes** from the Rails 3 format to Rails 4.

```
# Rails 3, this works fine.
class Mobileownerdisclosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mobileuser, foreign_key: 'mobileowner_id', conditions: "mobileownerdisclosures.mobileowner_type = 'Mobileuser'", include: :mobileownerdisclosures
end

# Rails 4 format that I can not get to work...
class Mobileownerdisclosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mobileuser, -> { where("mobileownerdisclosures.mobileowner_type = 'Mobileuser'").includes(:mobileownerdisclosures) }, foreign_key: 'mobileowner_id'
end
```

The **.includes(:mobileownerdisclosures)** just doesn't seem to be considered at all.  However, if I change this from an **includes** to a **joins**, it works fine.

```
# Rails 4 format with joins instead of includes.
class Mobileownerdisclosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mobileuser, -> { where("mobileownerdisclosures.mobileowner_type = 'Mobileuser'").joins(:mobileownerdisclosures) }, foreign_key: 'mobileowner_id'
end
```

But since I am converting a very large project from Rails 3 to Rails 4, I'd rather keep it includes like the original intent, just to be sure the original coder didn't need it this way.

Why is the includes not being considered?  Is there a different way to use includes other than what I am doing there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) out.  I think you need to add .references(:mobileownerdisclosures) to let rails use the joined/eager loaded table in your where statement in the sql.

With a join you don't need to tell activerecord you're referencing the included table/relation in your where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
.eager_load(:mobileownerdisclosures)
```

instead of the `joins`/ `includes`?

'includes' now results in separate queries. So you don't have the joins in place for your WHERE conditions.

see http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: Sheesh, thanks neongrau.  I think I tried all the "other" ones, other than eager_load.  haha  That seems to have done it.  The rails console output looks  identical from 3 to 4 now.

Comment: Thank you neongrau.